# Setting attr.required to "CONDITION" does not check anything

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I'm creating a form, where a input field should/ shouldn't be required based on a previous condition (e.g. a checkbox).

If the `required` attribute is set an the element, the required validation works just fine. If I set the  `required` attribute with [attr.required]="CONDITION", it doesn't check it at all.

Here is a plnkr sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/vPfmgvLxUjNyNXHtkY24
(based on on the [hero example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/form-validation/eplnkr.html) from the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)).

Code (relevent part):

```
  <form #heroForm="ngForm">  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Required label Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="cbReqired" name="cbReqired" id="cbReqired">
      </div>

      <div [hidden]="!cbReqired">Now the Textbox should be required! (<code>required="true"</code> is set!)</div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" [attr.required]="cbReqired" [(ngModel)]="hero" #name="ngModel">

        <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

          <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
            Name is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="heroForm.invalid">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="heroForm.resetForm({})">Reset</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Use [required], not [attr.required].

Comment: What is the question? Angular uses directive for required and it sets attribute internally depending on value you provided in property. so you need to use `[required]="val"` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L79

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use `[required]` instead of `[attr.required]`. Here is the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/B6dM2BvD3hMH3Skv6uy5?p=preview

Comment: okay... so now it works and was that simple.. wow :D (7min more till I can accept it)

Comment: Great! But I really have no idea, why `[attr.required]` doesn't work...

Comment: If someone knows, I might switch accepted answer :)

Comment: It is probably because the `[attr.required]` does not add the attribute in the DOM soon enough so the `RequiredValidator` directive can be activated. Doing with the angular binding with `[required]` seems to trigger something else than the attribute value change, also adding the validation directives to the element.